# Inputting values for jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, split, jagged-arrays

Ok, I'm attempting to make a simple program that reads in number of pizzas sold for a given day and then have the user input the type of pizza sold for that day (with this I need to use the Split() with the user input).

I'm having issues populating the columns for my jagged array.

Now, I can get what I have to work for only 1 pizza sold, but anything beyond that it is not taking in my user input for the type of pizzas sold for that day (the column values). It's not reading in the user input as separate items so once I input, it goes to the next line like it's waiting for data instead of moving on. (Since I'm testing this for one day, it would end the program once the user input was read in).

I'm not quite sure where my issue is with my loops putting in my column values, but I'm figuring it has something with reading in the user input and placing that in the column of the jagged array. Any help would be great.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Greeting();
        string[][] pizza = new string[7][];
        GetPizzas(pizza);

    }

    static void Greeting()
    {
        Write("Welcome to Z's Pizza Report!");
    }

    static void GetPizzas(string[][] array)
    {
        int numOfPizza;
        string day;
        for (int r = 0; r < array.Length; r++)
        {
            if (r == 0)
            {
                day = "Monday";
                Write("How many total pizzas were there for {0}? ", day);
                numOfPizza = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                while (numOfPizza < 0)
                {
                    Write("Number cannot be negative. Try Again: ");
                    numOfPizza = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                }

                array[r] = new string[numOfPizza];
                Write("Enter all the pizzas for {0}, seperated by spaces: ", day);

                for (int c = 0; c < array[r].Length; c++)
                {
                    string total = ReadLine();
                    array[c] = total.Split(' ');
                    while (array[r] != array[c])
                    {
                        Write("Input does not match number needed. Try Again: ");
                        total = ReadLine();
                        array[c] = total.Split(' ');
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (r == 1)
            {
                day = "Tuesday";
            }
            else if (r == 2)
            {
                day = "Wednesday";
            }
            else if (r == 3)
            {
                day = "Thursday";
            }
            else if (r == 4)
            {
                day = "Friday";
            }
            else if (r == 5)
            {
                day = "Saturday";
            }
            else
            {
                day = "Sunday";
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: what is `Write`?

Comment: I'm using `using static System.Console;` so I don't have to do `Console.` the whole time.

Comment: So, it is a bit odd that you do a `for` loop over your `array[r]`, doing a `ReadLine()` on each iteration, since you ask for all of the pizzas at once, separated by spaces.

Comment: You are dealing with jagged array[][] and during initialization you use array[]?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes I'm trying to populate the columns of my jagged array, is this not correct?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I have to use the Split() for this so I have to have an array[]. The material I have isn't the greatest when explaining jagged arrays, so anything more to expand on the explanation would be great.

Comment: Well, if you enter, say, 4 pizzas, it's going to do a `ReadLine()` 4 times, instead of just once, which is what I would have expected.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well it's populating the column for that row, so would the `for` loop for `array[r]` be needed to do so? That being said I want it to  `ReadLine()` once and then `Split()` that in to the values needed for the column. So if I have 2 pizzas I would enter cheese pep and the it would break that down to 2 values one being cheese and the other being pep since I sold 2 pizzas for that day. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Yeah, so you don't need the `for (int c = 0...` bit, because `Split()` returns an array. As Rufus shows in their answer, you can just set `array[r]` to the output of `Split()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems overly complicated to me, but does something like this help? Oh, notice that I'm using the built-in `DayOfWeek` enum to parse the friendly name for the day. The difference between this and yours is that `Sunday` is day `0`.

This line of code casts the integer to the enum, and then gets the string value:

```
var dayOfWeek = ((DayOfWeek)i).ToString();
```

I also added a helper function to get an integer from the user. It takes in a prompt string, an error string, an optional min value and an optional max value, then it prompts the user for an integer and won't return until they enter a valid value:

```
static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, string error, 
    int minValue = int.MinValue, int maxValue = int.MaxValue)
{
    int result;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prompt)) Console.Write(prompt);

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) 
           || result < minValue || result > maxValue)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) Console.Write(error);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The rest of the code looks like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pizzasSold = new string[7][];

    GetPizzas(pizzasSold);

    for (int i = 0; i < pizzasSold.Length; i++)
    {
        var dayOfWeek = ((DayOfWeek)i).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("You sold {0} pizzas on {1}: {2}", 
            pizzasSold[i].Length, dayOfWeek, string.Join(", ", pizzasSold[i]));
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void GetPizzas(string[][] array)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < array.Length; r++)
    {
        var dayOfWeek = ((DayOfWeek)r).ToString();

        var numPizzasSold =
                GetIntFromUser($"How many total pizzas were there for {dayOfWeek}? ",
                "Number cannot be negative. Try Again: ", 0);

        Console.Write($"Enter all the pizzas for {dayOfWeek}, seperated by spaces: ");
        var pizzasSold = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] { ' ' }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        while (pizzasSold.Length != numPizzasSold)
        {
            Console.Write($"Input does not match number needed. Try Again: ");
            pizzasSold = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] { ' ' }, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }

        array[r] = pizzasSold;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. This has to be formatted so that it asks how many were sold that day then based on that number, it then asks for the type of pizzas sold that day. There would be a check in place that would verify the type of pizzas entered matches the number of pizzas sold that day, if that makes sense. I'm totally aware that it is overly complicated and unfortunately it has to be that way.

Comment: Weird. Ok, updated answer with that requirement (and added a helper function that gets an int from the user)

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] n = new int[3][];
            int i;
            n[0] = new int[4];
            n[1] = new int[3];
            n[2] = new int[2];
            // n[1] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            // Console.WriteLine("enter the rollno");
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {

                n[0][i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            }
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {

                n[1][i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            }
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {

                n[2][i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            }


            //   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            // {
            //   n[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //}

            for (i = 0; i <4; i++)
            
                              {
                    Console.Write(n[0][i] + " ");
                }
            Console.WriteLine();
           for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            
                    {
                        Console.Write(n[1][i] + " ");
                    }

                

            }
    }
}
```